# Convert &[Box<[u8]>] to String or &str

Tags: rust

What's an efficient way to convert a result of type `&[Box<[u8]>]` into something more readily consumed like `String` or `&str`?

An example function is the [`txt_data()` method from `trust_dns_proto::rr:rdat::txt::TXT`](https://docs.rs/trust-dns-proto/0.19.5/trust_dns_proto/rr/rdata/txt/struct.TXT.html).

I've tried several things that seem to go nowhere, like:

```rust
fn main() {
    let raw: &[Box<[u8]>] = &["Hello", " world!"]
        .iter()
        .map(|i| i.as_bytes().to_vec().into_boxed_slice())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let value = raw.iter().map(|s| String::from(*s)).join("");

    assert_eq!(value, "Hello world!");
}
```

Where `raw` is of that type.

Comment: I really wonder how you end up with a `&[Box<[u8]>]`

Comment: @Stargateur It's part of the API. It's also very bizarre.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to convert an array of octets to `str` directly cause the data is split up. So a `String` look like a good candidate.

I would use [`str::from_utf8()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_utf8.html) combined with [`try_fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold):

```rust
use std::str;

fn main() {
    let raw: &[Box<[u8]>] = &["Hello", " world!"]
        .iter()
        .map(|i| i.as_bytes().to_vec().into_boxed_slice())
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let value = raw
        .iter()
        .map(|i| str::from_utf8(i))
        .try_fold(String::new(), |a, i| {
            i.map(|i| {
                let mut a = a;
                a.push_str(i);
                a
            })
        });

    assert_eq!(value.as_ref().map(|x| x.as_str()), Ok("Hello world!"));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the solution is this:

```rust
let value: String = raw
    .iter()
    .map(|s| String::from_utf8((*s).to_vec()).unwrap())
    .collect::<Vec<String>>()
    .join("");
```

Where the key is `from_utf8()` and the `(*s).to_vec()` suggested by `rustc`.

Comment: Note that `String::from_utf8((*s).to_vec()).unwrap()` would allocate even if data is not valid. Could be a bottleneck if your date is often expected to be invalid.